# Differentiation Matrix for central-difference scheme?

Tags: matrices, derivatives

Central-difference scheme is defined to be:

$f'(x) = \frac{f(x+d(x)) - f(x-d(x)))} {2*d(x)} + O(d(x)^2)$

Assume periodic boundary conditions, so that: $f(n+1)=f(1)$

I understand how to find all the center values of the matrix, but what I don't get is the first and last rows using the "periodic boundary condition" statement.

$\left[ {\begin{array}{ccccc}
 f_1'(x) \\
 f_2'(x) \\
 f_3'(x) \\
... \\
 f_n'(x)\\
  \end{array} } \right] =
\frac{1} {2*d(x)} * 
A * \left[ {\begin{array}{ccccc}
 f_1(x) \\
 f_2(x) \\
 f_3(x) \\
... \\
 f_n(x)\\
  \end{array} } \right]$

Where A is a matrix with $1$'s, $0$'s and $-1$'s.
What I have is that the upper diagonal will be all 1's and the lower will be -1's and the actual diagonal is all 0's and rest is 0 too. Except the first and the last row, can someone help me with those?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$
A =
\pmatrix{  0 & 1     &   0    &        & \dots  &  -1     \cr
          -1 &  0     &  1    &        &        &        \cr
           0 & -1     &   0    & 1     & \ddots & \vdots \cr
      \vdots & \ddots &        & \ddots &        &        \cr
             &        &        &  -1    &   0    & 1     \cr
           1 & \dots  &        &  0     &  -1    &  0     \cr}
$$

Comment: How did you get the first and last?

Comment: Note that $f_1(x) = f_{n+1}(x)$, so $f_1'(x) = f_{n+1}'(x)$. According to the central difference scheme we have $f_1'(x) = (f_2(x) - f_0(x))/2d$ and $f_{n+1}'(x) = (f_{n+2}(x) - f_n(x))/2d$. Therefore $f_1'(x) = f_{n+1}'(x) = (f_2(x) - f_n(x))/2d$. Similar argument for the last row.

Comment: Understood, thank you!

Comment: Quick question @yuan-gao how did you cancel $-f_0(x)$ and $fn+2(x)$?

Comment: Imagine extending the domain to another period. Then $f_1(x), f_2(x), \ldots, f_n(x)$ is essentially the same as $f_{n+1}(x), f_{n+2}(x), \ldots, f_{2n}(x)$.

Comment: Right, that makes sense, thanks again!